# How to avoid embedded `std::complex` when providing `T=std::complex<Q>`?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, complex-numbers

For a Polynomial equation solver, it would be great to template it to have any type available:

```
template <class number, int degree>
class PolynomialEquation
{
public:

private:
    array<number, degree+1> myEquation;
    array<complex<number>, degree> equationResult;
};
```

This allows, for example, `double`in ℝ to be used for the input, and the result to be `std::complex<double>` in ℂ (we know that from degree 2 and over, solution to equation usually fall into ℂ, example: x^2+1 ).

But, the input to the equation could also be a `std::complex`. In this case, the type of `myEquation` shall be complex, but `equationResult` should NOT be a `std::complex<complex<T>>`, but just a normal complex number of type `T`.

**Questions:**

**How to make the type of `equationResult` to be the sub-type of `std::complex` when the equation is provided with `std::complex`?**

**Is there an `std::is_floating_point` equivalent like std::is_complex_number ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may create a traits, something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct to_complex {
    using type = std::complex<T>;
};

template <typename T>
struct to_complex<std::complex<T>> {
    using type = std::complex<T>;
};
```

And then

```
template <class number, int degree>
class PolynomialEquation
{
public:

private:
    array<number, degree+1> myEquation;
    array<typename to_complex<number>::type, degree> equationResult;
};
```

Comment: Probably I'd call it `poly_root_type_traits` or something like that - `to_complex` is a bit unclear about the rationale behind this thing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a trait for checking if the type is a complex number but it should be relatively easy to create one (also the alternative implementation to Jarod's `to_complex`):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct is_complex_number: std::false_type { };

template <class T>
struct is_complex_number<std::complex<T>>: std::true_type { };

template <class T>
struct to_complex: std::conditional<is_complex_number<T>::value, T, std::complex<T>> { };

int main() {
   std::cout << is_complex_number<float>::value << std::endl; // output: 0
   std::cout << is_complex_number<std::complex<float>>::value << std::endl; // output: 1
   typename to_complex<float>::type c; // decltype(c) == complex<float>
   typename to_complex<std::complex<float>>::type d; // decltype(d) == complex<float>
}
```

Comment: I can't think of any way to use std::same in a one-liner, do you ? Is there something in type_traits to check if T is a template template and if it is of the form U<V> ?

Comment: @Benoît if `V` is type template parameter one could create constexpr function with two overloads: `template <class> constexpr bool is_template_template() { return false; } template <template <class> class> constexpr bool is_template_template() { return true; }`. Unfortunately I don't know STL approach for that...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a C++14 one-liner alternative to @W.F.

```
using Complex = typename std::conditional<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, std::complex<T>, T>::type;
```

The assumption is that if it's not a arithmetic type, then it's should be a complex. If you wan't to be thorough, you need to make sure that T is either arithmetic (or even floating point) or complex. You would need to mix this with @W.F. anwser.

Answer (score 2):

I have a polynomial class where I potentially wanted real coefficients and complex x (as well as real, real and complex, complex).  I made a is_complex:

```
/**
 * Introspection class to detect if a type is std::complex.
 */
template<typename _Tp>
  struct is_complex : public std::false_type
  { };

/**
 * Introspection class to detect if a type is std::complex.
 */
template<>
  template<typename _Tp>
    struct is_complex<std::complex<_Tp>> : public std::true_type
    { };

/**
 * Introspection type to detect if a type is std::complex.
 */
template<typename _Tp>
  using is_complex_t = typename is_complex<_Tp>::type;

/**
 * Introspection variable template to detect if a type is std::complex.
 */
template<typename _Tp>
  constexpr bool is_complex_v = is_complex<_Tp>::value;
```

Also, I use tools to extract the scalar type whether the input is scalar or complex so I can use numeric limits facilities for example:

```
template<typename Tp>
  struct num_traits
  {
    using __value_type = Tp;
  };

template<>
  template<typename Tp>
    struct num_traits<std::complex<Tp>>
    {
      using __value_type = typename std::complex<Tp>::value_type;
    };

template<typename Tp>
  using num_traits_t = typename num_traits<Tp>::__value_type;
```

which I could use like this:

```
  using Val = num_traits_t<Ret>;
  constexpr auto eps = std::numeric_limits<Val>::epsilon();
```

and subsequently build convergence tests for both real and complex inputs.